# WtForms validators for email address

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Possible dumb question, so I apologize. I'm a newbie when it comes to Flask and WtForms in Python.

So, I want to include a validation in my email field, to check if the input contains a @ symbol for example, followed by something and then .com in the end.

Right now, my code for this email field looks like this:

```
email = StringField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(max=60)])
```

What do I need to add to include a check for @something.com in the input gotten from the form?

Comment: I've found it too, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I need to check somehow that the input contains that terminology specific to an email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the email validator

```py
from wtforms import validators
email = StringField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(max=60), validators.Email()])
```

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.Email

Or you can write a custom validator

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#custom-validators